# Autosys job stays in Running status

Tags: .net, autosys

I have a .Net exe sitting on a Windows Server, I have an Autosys job set up to launch the app. When I start the job it just stays in Running status but the app never runs. The app takes about 5 minutes to run. It downloads some images, zips them, and then moves the file to another server. I can run the app successfully from the cmd line. I am not receiving any error messages and the job keeps saying its running. I am new to Autosys and I was looking for some advice on what to do to troubleshoot. Thanks.

The correct Framework is on the server that the app was targeting.

Answer (score 1):

When the autosys job is running I would check the job's log file on the Windows server. Open up a Autosys Command prompt and run the autosyslog -J  to read the log. Checking for any error messages and specifically for what the PID is of the child process that runs the command. Then check in Task Manager to see if that PID is running.

Also when the job is running do a autorep -d -J  to get a detailed run report and see if there are any error messages?

Troubleshooting these issues on Windows can be a pain. I would suspect the environment from where it works when you run it from the command line and what it is in Autosys is different. Are you running your command line as the SAME owner ID as in the Autosys job? If examining the client log doesn't help, next I would run the set command logged is as the job  owner ID saving the output to a file, then create a copy of the problem job, replacing the command with set and piping the output to a file. Then compare the two files for differences.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain some more useful debugging information from an Autosys daemon log file. It is typically located inside a tmp folder under the path where Autosys agent is installed (for instance C:\Program Files (x86)\CA\UnicenterAutoSysJM.DEV\tmp). You will need to go through all the files located in this folder to locate the file that corresponds to the particular job you are looking for.

This file contains the actual the command that the Autosys agent used to start your program and also other environment variables that are set by Autosys.

Answer (score 0):

When a job is stuck in the starting or running condition this means that the Autosys event processor communicated with the Windows remote agent and passed all the information for the remote agent to run the job. However, that remote agent was not able to communicate to the DB to inform the status of job which it ran.

You might want to check if the windows remote agent has connectivity with the database.
This can be identified by using command “autoping -m WindowsMachineName -D”

For example, following outlines the issue:-

```
<AutosysCommandPrompt>: autoping -m WindowsMachineName -D

AutoPinging Machine [WindowsMachineName]  AND checking the Remote Agent's DB Access.
  ERROR: AutoPing WAS NOT SUCCESSFUL!

   Remote Agent on WindowsMachineName could not connect to DB: xxxxxxxx.WORLD
```

Now, in this case, investigate the tnsnames.ora file and make sure that the database name is in it. This could be one of the reason for DB connect failure.
Once this is done, you should get following output from previous command.

```
<AutosysCommandPrompt>: autoping -m WindowsMachineName -D

AutoPinging Machine [WindowsMachineName]  AND checking the Remote Agent's DB Access.
  AutoPing WAS SUCCESSFUL!
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to check is to change the job command to execute "path", compair the user privileges with the user you used from the command line.